# List top processes of one user across machines?

Tags: top

Is there a cross-machine `top -u myUsername` command that I can see my processes (along with their CPU usages) across all the specified machines?

If not, I have an idea in mind. I can write a script that SSH into a machine, `top -u myUsername`, then SSH into the next machine, `top -u myUsername` again, ..., finally compile everything and display on my current logged in machine. I am not sure how I can "return" the `top` results from a secondary session to my current session.

Is there a better or more elegant way?

Comment: Use `top -b`  as batch mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for i in $(cat server_list); do ssh $i 'hostname;top -b -n1 -u myUsername'; done >> mytop.out
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmmm, I would like something dynamic, like top itself. Keeping refreshing in a terminal window.